# Undefined variable: institutions (View:

Tags: laravel-5, formulário

Caros,

Estou com um erro bem chato e persistente.

Undefined variable: institutions (View:

Já procurei varias vezes e não sei o porque os dados não são passados para o form.

Controller

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\OcorrenciaRequest;
use Carbon\Carbon;

use App\Ocorrencia;

class OcorrenciasController extends Controller
{
    //public function __construct()
    //{

```
//}

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index()
{
    //variavel #ocorrencias amarzena o comteudo do model/bd (Ocorrencia) e realiza a paginação      
    $ocorrencias = Ocorrencia::paginate(5);
    //$ocorrencias = Ocorrencia::all();

    //Compact na variavel ocorrencias (Array)
    return view('ocorrencias.index', compact('ocorrencias'));
    //dd(hora_final, hora_inicial)

}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function create()
{
    //retorna a função create na view
    return view('ocorrencias.create');
    //return view('ocorrencias.create')->with('institutions',Institution::lists('name','id'));

}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  Request  $request
 * @return Response
 */
//
public function store(OcorrenciaRequest $request)
{
    $ocorrencia = Ocorrencia::create($request->all());

    $ocorrencia = $this->setOcorrenciaRelations($ocorrencia, $request);        
    $ocorrencia->save();

    return redirect()->route('ocorrencia.index');
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */

public function show(Ocorrencia $ocorrencia)
{
    return view('ocorrencias.show', compact('ocorrencia'));
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */

public function edit(Ocorrencia $ocorrencia)
{
    //Compact na variavel ocorrencia.
    return view('ocorrencias.edit', compact('ocorrencia'));
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */

public function update(OcorrenciaRequest $request, Ocorrencia $ocorrencia)
{
    $ocorrencia->update($request->all());

    $ocorrencia = $this->setOcorrenciaRelations($ocorrencia, $request);
    $ocorrencia->save();

    return redirect()->route('ocorrencia.index');
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */

public function destroy(Ocorrencia $ocorrencia)
{
    $ocorrencia->delete();

    return redirect()->route('ocorrencia.index');
}

private function setOcorrenciaRelations(Ocorrencia $ocorrencia, Request $request)
{
    $institution = Institution::findOrFail($request->institution_id);
    $ocorrencia->institution()->associate($institution);
    $aplication = Aplication::findOrFail($request->aplication_id);
    $ocorrencia->aplication()->associate($aplication);
    $ocorrencia->causes()->sync($request->causes_list);
    //$user = User::findOrFail($request->user_id);
    //$ocorrencia->user()->associate($user);

    return $ocorrencia;


}
```

}

Form

{!! Form::label('data_inicial', 'Data Inicial') !!}
    {!! Form::date('data_inicial', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Data Inicial']) !!}



    {!! Form::label('data_inicial', 'Hora Inicial') !!}
    {!! Form::time('data_inicial', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Hora Inicial']) !!}



    {!! Form::label('data_final', 'Data Final') !!}
    {!! Form::date('data_final', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Data Final']) !!}



    {!! Form::label('hora_final', 'Hora Final') !!}
    {!! Form::time('hora_final', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Hora Final']) !!}



    {!! Form::label('institution_id', 'Instituição') !!}
    {!! Form::select('institution_id', $institutions, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Selecione uma Instituição...']) !!}



    {!! Form::label('logados', 'Logados') !!}
    {!! Form::text('logados', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Logados']) !!}



    {!! Form::label('institution_id', 'Instituição') !!}
    {!! Form::select('institution_id', $institutions, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Selecione uma Instituição...']) !!}



    {!! Form::label('observacao', 'Ocorrência') !!}
    {!! Form::textarea('observacao', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Ocorrência...']) !!}

{!! Form::submit('Enviar', ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) !!}

Model

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Ocorrencia extends Model
{

//protected $table = "ocorrencias";

protected $fillable = [

`'data_inicial',
        'hora_inicial',
        'data_final',
        'hora_final',
        'logados',
        'observacao'
    ];


public function institution()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Institution');
}

public function causes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Cause');
}

    public function aplication()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Aplication');
}

/*public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}*/
// Eloquent Accessor
// Cria uma nova propriedade dinamica
// Convenção: get + CampoEmCamelCase + Attribute
// Será convertido em $this->campo_em_camel_case
public function getCausesListAttribute()
{
    return $this->causes->lists('id')->toArray();
}`

}

Comment: Pode explicar mais do seu código? qual método do controller você está tentando usar? pelo que vi, você não está passando essa variável para a view!

Comment: Estou tentando usar o create  <code>public function create()
    {
        //retorna a função create na view
        return view('occurrences.create');

    }
 </code>

Comment: então, você não está passando a variavel para a rota, você deve passar a variavel $institutions para sua view.